# Kivy - CustomDropdown - ScreenManager - failure

Tags: python, kivy

I´m trying to add a CustomDropDown to a button, but somehow it seems like the CustomDropDown-widget is initiated twice (dubble list) and when I click on a name I get the following answer:

**Error:**

```
File "C:\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 64, in custom_callback 
exec(__kvlang__.co_value, idmap)
   File "C:\Temp\privat\zucchini\my.kv", line 6, in <module>
     app.root.ids.btn.text = '{}'.format(args[1])
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 863, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__
 AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'
```

[image]

So yes, I fail to see what I´m doing wrong.. And thoughts are welcome! :)

**CODE:**

```
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class MainWindow(Screen):
    dropdown = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, **kw):
        super().__init__(**kw)
        self.cols = 1

class SecondWindow(Screen):
    pass

class MyApp(App):
    """
    """
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_file("my.kv")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

With the kv-file looking like:

```
#:import Factory kivy.factory.Factory

<CustomDropDown@DropDown>:
    id: dropdown
    on_select:
        app.root.ids.btn.text = '{}'.format(args[1])
        self.dismiss()

    Button:
        id: btn1
        text: 'name1'
        size_hint_y: None
        height: '32dp'
        on_release:
            dropdown.select(btn1.text)

    Button:
        id: btn2
        text: 'name2'
        size_hint_y: None
        height: '32dp'
        on_release:
            dropdown.select(btn2.text)

    Button:
        id: btn3
        text: 'name3'
        size_hint_y: None
        height: '32dp'
        on_release:
            dropdown.select(btn3.text)

WindowManager:
    MainWindow:
    SecondWindow:

<MainWindow>:
    name: "main"

    GridLayout:
        cols: 1

        GridLayout:
            cols: 1
        GridLayout:
            cols: 1

        GridLayout:
            cols: 2
            Button:
                id: btn
                text: 'Set name'
                on_release: Factory.CustomDropDown().open(self)
            Button:
                text: "Submit"
                on_release:
                    app.root.current = "second"
                    root.manager.transition.direction = "right"

<SecondWindow>:
    name: "second"
    Button:
        text: "Go Back"
        on_release:
            app.root.current = "main"
            root.manager.transition.direction = "left"
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly mate, you forgot to add to **from kivy.app import App** on your .py file.This code not giving me twice your button.It looks correct and gave me only 3 button as you wish.I showed you below how you can call which button clicked.And i suggest you that you can create these 3 button in .py file with a loop easily.Because these are looks like same.I hope this codes help you.

Its my code:

**My .py** file:

```
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.dropdown import DropDown

class CustomDropDown(DropDown):
    def give_my_value(self,value):
        print('Selected value is :',value)
class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class MainWindow(Screen):
    dropdown = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, **kw):
        super().__init__(**kw)
        self.cols = 1

class SecondWindow(Screen):
    pass

class MyApp(App):
    """
    """
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_file("my.kv")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

**my.kv** file:

```
#:import Factory kivy.factory.Factory
<CustomDropDown@DropDown>:
    id: dropdown
    on_select:
        self.dismiss()
    Button:
        id: btn1
        text: 'name1'
        size_hint_y: None
        height: '32dp'
        on_release:
            dropdown.give_my_value(self.text)
            dropdown.dismiss()
    Button:
        id: btn2
        text: 'name2'
        size_hint_y: None
        height: '32dp'
        on_release:
            dropdown.give_my_value(self.text)
            dropdown.dismiss()
    Button:
        id: btn3
        text: 'name3'
        size_hint_y: None
        height: '32dp'
        on_release:
            dropdown.give_my_value(self.text)
            dropdown.dismiss()
WindowManager:
    MainWindow:
    SecondWindow:
<MainWindow>:
    name: "main"
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        GridLayout:
            cols: 1
        GridLayout:
            cols: 1
        GridLayout:
            cols: 2
            Button:
                id: btn
                text: 'Set name'
                on_release: Factory.CustomDropDown().open(self)
            Button:
                text: "Submit"
                on_release:
                    app.root.current = "second"
                    root.manager.transition.direction = "right"

<SecondWindow>:
    name: "second"
    Button:
        text: "Go Back"
        on_release:
            app.root.current = "main"
            root.manager.transition.direction = "left"
```

Comment: Thank you! I don´t get any erroers now, however I do still get the dubble namelist.. But I´ll try to create the buttons in the py-file instead :)

Comment: I don't know why its doubled on you. Creating same sized buttons in .py file with loops takes less times. If my answer has resolved your issue, I would ask you to give useful answer ;)

Comment: Yep, creating the buttons in the py-file did the trick :)